# Nitrogen wf.hrl file is deleted with a warning

Tags: yaws, cowboy, nitrogen, webmachine, inets

I am using a slim_version of cowboy, I have also tried that on slim_yaws on nitrogen. What puzzles me is the abrupt deletion of the wf.hrl file by the VM. I do not understand what causes this!! Here is what appears in the console.

```
Warning. Deleted "wf.hrl" file included in existing src files: [list_module_files_with_the_wf.hrl_include >]
```

I am puzzled because the module which use the wf.hrl cannot compile after its deletion. I have experienced it on **slim_cowboy** and **slim_yaws**. It is abrupt!

Comment: Can you provide more details about your environment and the steps to reproduce the problem. I tried the latest version of Nitrogen on OS X 10.10.1 with R17 and I don't get the same error.

Comment: I am using **Ubuntu 14.04LTS**, is have build the **nitrogen slim_server versions** using [Basho's patched version of Erlang](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/quickstart/). In summary the environment was set up [as at this link latest answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222478/including-the-erlang-client-library-from-riak-in-nitrogen/27585960#27585960).

Comment: Have you noticed it do it only after running `make`?  There was an issue similar to this a while back that was solved involving the do-plugins.escript script. Perhaps try updating your do-plugins.escript from the latest (https://github.com/nitrogen/nitrogen/blob/master/rel/overlay/common/do-plugins.escript)

Comment: Any luck with this, Vianney?

Comment: Yes, ever since i used `do-plugins.escript`, it has never happened again! Thanks.